Rendering meshes in a dataloader
I believe that mesh rendering should not be a very expensive operation, since games do that very efficiently. Yet, works I am aware of are doing mesh rendering as a preprocessing step:
The state of the art:

Given: Mesh dataset with texture, pre-defined camera parameters (intrinsics matrix) and world-to-camera transformations (extrinsics matrix)
Pre-processing: In an offline setting, looping through the mesh dataset, render images & depth maps & foreground maps and save them with their respective camera parameters.
Training: Use torch.utils.data.Dataset.__getitem__() to load these parameters.

Problems:

Disk space.
We cannot render every view.
Some libraries require GPU utilization to do the rendering. We cannot afford to occupy GPU with this preprocessing step.

How I wish it to be:
Instead, handle the mesh rendering within the pytorch dataloader worker process. Specifically, I am looking for something in the spirit of:
class MeshRenderingDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    ...
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        loaded_mesh = load_mesh(self.mesh_paths[idx])
        # Lets say all camera intrinsics are the same and defined in init
        intr = self.intr
        # This method should return a random extr. that surely looks towards the mesh.
        extr = self.get_random_pose_around_mesh() 
        rgb, depth, mask = loaded_mesh.render(intr,extr)
        return rgb, depth, mask, intr, extr

This rendering operation does not need to be differentiable.
Any ideas on how to achieve load_mesh and loaded_mesh.render() efficiently, such that the pytorch workers can handle this task? If you think this is not possible, an explanation would be also much appreciated!
